# Setting iframe height with Javascript based on content

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have an external javascript that is called into a html page. The lines of javascript I am having problems with are as follows:

```
document.getElementById('lsb').innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://domain.com/feeds/" id="frame" frameBorder="0" style="border: none; width: 100%; min-width: 100%;" onLoad="calcHeight();" ></iframe>';

function calcHeight(){
    var the_height= document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById('frame').height=the_height;
}
```

Now the interesting part is that this code works, when the fame is called the height is adjusted to that of its content so there is no scroll bar. However, if the src value of the iframe is not local to the javascript file and html then it doesn't work, the height value is not set.

Does anyone know why this is, or have an alternative script?

Thanks in advance, and happy valentines day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross-domain issue, most browsers will not allow you to access/manipulate contents coming from different domain. This is a browser security restrictions.

Comment: In this instance I am not edited the contents of the external file. I am just trying to edit the iframe that I am creating, so that its height is equal to that of the content contained within it.

Comment: access and manipulation are both disallowed, to work around this you have to create some sort of a proxy script(running on the same domain), that will download the contents from remote source and render it.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start with a proxy script, is there perhaps another way to get the iframe to allow all content to display without a scroll bar?